# OpenCv No rule to make target

Tags: c++, c, opencv, makefile

this is my first example with OpenCv:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  IplImage* img = 0;

  img=cvLoadImage("/home/michele/Pictures/sensor.png");     // carica l'immagine

  cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);       // crea la finestra

  cvShowImage("mainWin", img );    //  mostra l'immagine

  cvWaitKey(0);    // wait for a key

  cvReleaseImage(&img );    //rilascia l'immagine

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

If I click on BuildAll I've this error returned:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `1st.o', needed by `firstOpenCV'.  Stop.
```

What I have to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to [see a tutorial](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Eclipse) on how to configure Eclipse.

You could also try to compile your application manually (from the cmd-line):

```
g++ 1st.cpp -o app `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```